# what is the advantage of declaring a reference variable as an interface type in JAVA?

Tags: java, interface

I was reading [this PowerPoint presentation](http://www.lsp4you.com/java/javaimages/06_Packages%20&%20Interfaces.ppt) when I came across this:

> When you call a method through one of these references, the correct version will be called based on the actual instance of the interface being referred to. This is one of the key features of interfaces. The method to be executed is looked up dynamically at run time, allowing classes to be created later than the code which calls methods on them.

Can anyone explain me about this concept? I referred few websites and book and I am still not clear about how this concept works. From above line it is known that it calls correct version of method. How does it work and when should I cast an object to interface type.

Comment: If this question is about Java then why did you tag it JavaScript *as well*??

Comment: Code to Interfaces e.g. List not ArrayList

Comment: Implementing against an interface makes your code more flexible. You don't expect a special implementation if your parameter is an interface.

Comment: Is the first paragraph a quote from somewhere? If so, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's give an example using the `List` interface. Two of its implementations are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. The first one is really fast at retrieving a random element (for example the 6th using `get(5)` method) but is slow at adding and removing elements. The second one is the opposite. Fast at adding and removing but slow at accessing random elements.

Now lets assume that you have a class that has methods that retrieve information about a car dealership. One method retrieves a list of all available car manufacturers while the other method retrieves all the cars the dealership has. In the first case you would want to use an `ArrayList` because you don't expect the list of manufacturers to change that much, whereas in the second case you want a `LinkedList` because you expect to sell and buy lots of cars thus making many changes.

However, the one who *uses* those methods, doesn't really care whether he handles an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`. All he wants to do is use `get(x)` and `add(Car)` or `remove(Car)`  which are all methods of the `List` interface. Thus, your methods should all have `List` as their return type and **they** will decide what *implementation* they will provide, since it doesn't matter to the one calling them.

This also gives you the advantage of being able to, in the future, *change* the second method for example from providing a `LinkedList` into an `ArrayList` if you decide that you need fast retrieval instead of fast adding and removing. If the method was explicitly returning `LinkedList` you would have to go and change all the places that it was being called into the new type. But if it was returning simply the interface then no outside change is required!